# Operation is invalid after previous operation

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am making some good progress on my social networking application. I have run into an issue. I have a ViewController that provides a TableView that is populated with content from my parse database. In the cells I have a RSVP button that is supposed to send a RSVP based on the indexPath to the database when clicked and remove when it is clicked again. I believe my logic is correct, however, I keep receiving the error:

> Operation is invalid after previous operation.

I placed a breakpoint to locate the cause of the crash and I have identified that it is happening at the addUniqueObject line within the rsvpButtonClicked IBOutlet function.

Can someone help me? My code is below.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class MainFeedViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var eventsTable: UITableView!

var user = PFUser.currentUser()
var refresher: UIRefreshControl!

var eventId = [String]()
var eventNames = [String]()
var eventCity = [String]()
var imageFiles = [PFFile]()
var getEventsQuery = 0
var userRsvps = [NSArray]()
var rsvp = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getuserlocation()
    getTodayDate()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    refreshControl()
    //getMyRsvps()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: "eventQuery", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}


func getMyRsvps() {
    var getRsvps = PFUser.query()
    getRsvps.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: user.objectId)
    getRsvps.whereKeyExists("myrsvp")
    getRsvps.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            self.userRsvps.append(objects)
        }
    }
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.eventsTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mainFeedContent") as MainFeedContentTableViewCell

    cell.eventName.text = eventNames[indexPath.row]
    imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            cell.eventImage.image = image
        }
    }

    cell.rsvpButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.rsvpButton.addTarget(self, action: "rsvpButtonClick:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return cell
}

@IBAction func rsvpButtonClick(sender: UIButton) {
    var senderButton = sender
    println("Current row \(senderButton.tag)")

    var tempObject = eventId[senderButton.tag]
    println("\(tempObject)")

    PFUser.currentUser().addUniqueObject(tempObject, forKey: "myrsvp")
    PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackground()

}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return eventId.count
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let mainViewIdentifier = "showDetail"
    if segue.identifier == mainViewIdentifier {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewController {
            if let feedIndex = eventsTable.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row {
                destination.eventNames = eventNames[feedIndex]
                destination.eventId = eventId[feedIndex]
                destination.eventImagesFile = imageFiles[feedIndex]
            }
        }
    }
}

func eventQuery() {
    let getEventsQuery = PFQuery(className: "Events")
    getEventsQuery.whereKey("eventLocation", nearGeoPoint: user["location"] as PFGeoPoint, withinMiles: user["preferredDistanceEvents"] as Double)
    getEventsQuery.limit = 16
    getEventsQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) events")
            for object in objects {
                self.eventId.append(object.objectId)
                self.eventNames.append(object["eventName"] as String)
                self.eventCity.append(object["eventCity"] as String)
                self.imageFiles.append(object["eventPicture"] as PFFile)
                self.eventsTable.reloadData()
            }
        } else {
            println(error)
        }
    }
}

func refreshControl() {

    refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.eventsTable.addSubview(refresher)

}

/*
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

    var height: CGFloat = scrollView.frame.size.height
    var contentYoffset: CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    var distanceFromBottom: CGFloat = scrollView.contentSize.height - contentYoffset
    if distanceFromBottom <= height {
        println("End of Table")
        refresh()
    }
}
*/

func refresh() {
    self.getEventsQuery++
    if self.getEventsQuery < self.eventId.count {
        let refreshEventsQuery = PFQuery(className: "Events")
        refreshEventsQuery.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: user["location"] as PFGeoPoint, withinMiles: user["preferredDistanceEvents"] as Double)
        refreshEventsQuery.whereKey("objectId", notContainedIn: eventId)
        refreshEventsQuery.limit = 4
        refreshEventsQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) events")
                for object in objects {
                    self.eventNames.append(object["eventName"] as String)
                    self.eventCity.append(object["City"] as String)
                    self.imageFiles.append(object["eventPicture"] as PFFile)
                    self.eventId.append(object.objectId)
                    self.eventsTable.reloadData()
                }
            } else {
                println(error)
            }
        }
    } else {
        println("No More Events. Sorry")
    }
    self.refresher.endRefreshing()
}

func getuserlocation() {
    PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (geopoint: PFGeoPoint!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            self.user["location"] = geopoint
            self.user.saveInBackground()
        }
    }
}

func getTodayDate(){
    var today = NSDate()
    var calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    var flags = NSCalendarUnit.HourCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnit.MinuteCalendarUnit
    var components = calendar.components(flags, fromDate: today)
    var hour = components.hour
    var minutes = components.minute

    println("Today is \(today). The time is \(hour):\(minutes)")
}

}
```

Comment: What is `myrsvp` is the model on the server? A pointer? An array? A relationship?

Comment: It is an array type on my parse database.

Comment: myrsvp essentially is an array consisting of all event ids of the events the user rsvp'd to.

Comment: Did you ever call `fetch:` on the `currentUser` ?

Comment: No I do not call fetch on the currentUser. I have the user login and and create a new currentUser session.

Comment: This view only queries the database of events based on a geopoint location constraint. When the user clicks on the like icon, I want that icon provide the eventId as a value in the myrsvp array

Comment: Now that I am writing this out, should it be an array of pointers? Because I have another view that I will have a table query the database based on the myrsvp contents.

Comment: And it's the first time you try to use `myrsvp` for anything directly on the user object that you have the issue? I'd try fetching the user so the SDK knows the key actually exists. It can be an array of anything (that can be encoded to JSON). Whether it will be more useful to you as an array of pointers or a relationship is a different question.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a bug in parse (in code shared with JS, because I've experienced the problem there).  Specifically, this failure appears when intermixing the add and remove `PFObject` methods to manipulate array columns.

I've used both of the following workarounds with some success:

1. Delimit adds and removes with intervening saves.  In other words, build your own `addToColAndSave` and `removeFromColAndSave` convenience methods.  If you've called one of them, don't call the other until the save completes.
2. Probably easier: restructure the code to avoid the add/remove methods on arrays.  Instead, use the getter (`get` in JS, `objectForKey:` in iOS) to get the array in memory, then manipulate it natively.  Use the sdk setter to update the object.

Comment: Interesting approach. Will try both!